# multiple condition in join

Tags: sql, mysql, join

how can i use two or more condition on join?
i want to replace this query with join version of it:

```
select * 
from t1,t2 
where t1.a=t2.b and t1.c=t2.d and t1.e=t2.f
```

how could it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
select * 
from t1
join t2 
on t1.a = t2.b and t1.c = t2.d and t1.e = t2.f
```